# backbone.js - refreshing a collection every second?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm messing with backbone.js [Todos](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html) for the first time. I'm trying to add a timer each Todo, which is fine, but the timer won't refresh until I refresh the page, and I want it to refresh every second.

The AppView contains this:

```
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
          _.bindAll(this, 'addAll');
          Todos.bind('refresh', this.addAll);
          Todos.fetch();
    },

    addAll: function() {
      Todos.each(this.addOne);
    },
}
```

So I figured I could reload it every second like this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){ 
  window.Todos.refresh();
}, 1000);
```

addAll is called and I get no errors on the console, but the view does not update.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Backbone are you using? `refresh` was renamed to `reset` way back in 0.5.0 and we're at 0.9.2 now. And how do you know that your `setInterval` callback isn't being triggered?

Comment: @muistooshort I'll check that now, as I'm actually using something I forked from github and may be out of date

Comment: It's not part of your question, but you really should use a flow control library. Doing intensive operations inside of a setInterval can easily overwhelm the browser, resulting in a spinny-wheel or even browser crash. See https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js and http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to do it by manually triggering the model's change event. This works because the view's render function is bound to the model by `this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);`

(In this scenario, `Todos` is a collection of `Todo` models

```
Todos.each(function (todo) { 
    todo.trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that this line:

```
Todos.each(this.addOne);
```

Is incorrect. You probably want something like this:

```
Todos.each(_.bind(this.addOne,this));
```

Comment: Didn't work. That code comes with the example anyway, the only thing I've added is the `window.setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Yea, as @muistooshort asked above, how do you know what the timer isn't updated? Try this

```
window.setInterval(function(){ 
  window.Todos.refresh(); // or .reset() if you've updated backbone.js
  console.log('tick');
}, 1000);
```

I think you see that `setInterval` works.